# After setting new language: TextToSpeech.onInitListener is called before new TextToSpeech(..) instance is returned

Tags: android, text-to-speech

i ran into an unexpected problem with `onInit(..)` for a new `TextToSpeech` instance on Android.

All code samples i found assume that the new instance is returned to the caller before `onOnit(..)` is called, so that the return value is usable to access the new `TextToSpeech` instance.

After changing the default language for the phone my activity is restarted (as expected) and i create a new `TextToSpeech` instance as usual. But in this case the `onInit(..)` callback is called *before* new `TextToSpeech(..)` returns the instance. Any setup in `onInit(..)` uses an outdated instance or `null`.

```
public static void startTTS()
{   
    tts_enabled = false;    
    texttospeech = null;
    texttospeech = new TextToSpeech(starter/*context*/,new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
    {
        public void onInit(int status)
        {
            if(texttospeech==null) throw new RuntimeException("startTTS.onInit: texttospeech=null");

            boolean r = status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS;
            if(r) { init_tts(); tts_enabled = true; } 
            else texttospeech = null;
        }
    }); 
}
```

basically, in this example, the exeption throws.

i have tested this on a Huawei U8510 Android 2.3.3 and the emulator with Android 2.1.

what am i expected to do here?

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this problem and it showed, that the reason was quite different than assumed. My init-code was executed twice and two TextToSpeech instances were created and the two `onInit()`'s interleaved.

The reason for the init code beeing called twice is somewhat unexpected:

I have set the attribute `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for this activity and the documentation says that i get `onNewIntent()` and not `onCreate()` if the activity is already running. I assumed, and it seemed to be true, that i get `onNewIntent()` **instead** `onCreate()` but in some rare cases, e.g. after the user changed the timezone, i get `onNewIntent()` immedeately after and **in addition to** `onCreate()`. I don't believe that this behavior is intended.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very strange case.

I suggest using a LOCK, something like this:

```
ReentrantLock waitUntilInit = new ReentrantLock();
waitUntilInit.lock();

texttospeech = null;
    texttospeech = new TextToSpeech(starter/*context*/,new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
    {
        public void onInit(int status)
        {
            waitUntilInit.tryLock();
            if(texttospeech==null) throw new RuntimeException("startTTS.onInit: texttospeech=null");

            boolean r = status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS;
            if(r) { init_tts(); tts_enabled = true; } 
            else texttospeech = null;
        }
    });

if (waitUntilInit.isLocked())
waitUntilInit.unlock();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is resolved no, see my own answer.
<p>Thanks!